# How can I know what network interface devices the Linux kernel recognises?

Tags: networking, debian

I have been working with Debian Linux under a virtual machine (VirtualBox) and have noticed that, with the present virtual machine configuration, the EtherNet device that was configured in /etc/network/interfaces during the install was eth2 (I have generally expected eth0, eth1, etc.).  I have also noticed that there don't seem to be any ethX device files in the /dev directory.  This all has led me to wonder how, in a configuration where network capable devices are automatically detected, it is possible to know the names that the kernel assigns to those devices.  I assume that there is something in the /proc file system but, so far, I have been unable to see anything particular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see all networking devices by running:

```
ifconfig -a
```

Another trick to debugging the ethernet drivers is to look at dmesg:

```
dmesg|less
```

You will see each driver loading and creating ethernet devices.

You mention your ethernet device changing to eth2.  Did you copy or move the VM?  Typically when you make a copy of a VM it will re-create the MAC address so as to not conflict with the former copy.  If this happens `udev` will assign the "new card" another eth* device and save the previous device for the "missing" card.  These rules are stored in:

```
/etc/udev/rules.d/
```

Typically in a file called ##-persistant-net.rules.  You can safely remove the assignments stored in this file and reboot to have the ethernet devices reassigned.

Comment: I didn't copy or move the VM.  I believe that I changed the settings on the ethernet adapter from NAT to host.  That may have done it.